# What is the pyspark equivalent of MERGE INTO for databricks delta lake?

Tags: merge, databricks, delta-lake

The databricks [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/merge-into.html) describes how to do a merge for delta-tables.

In SQL the syntax

```
MERGE INTO [db_name.]target_table [AS target_alias]
USING [db_name.]source_table [<time_travel_version>] [AS source_alias]
ON <merge_condition>
[ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <condition> ] THEN <matched_action> ]
[ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <condition> ] THEN <matched_action> ]
[ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ AND <condition> ]  THEN <not_matched_action> ]
```

can be used. Is a python-equivalent available?

Comment: Delta lake is written in [Scala](https://github.com/delta-io) and the API itself support only Scala at the moment

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis: Thanks for the link. It turns out there is a [documented](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html) python api-available.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to find the documentation using the help of Alexandros Biratsis. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTable.merge). An example of such a merge is given by

```py
deltaTable.alias("events").merge(
    source = updatesDF.alias("updates"),
    condition = "events.eventId = updates.eventId"
  ).whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    {
      "data": "updates.data",
      "count": "events.count + 1"
    }
  ).whenNotMatchedInsert(values =
    {
      "date": "updates.date",
      "eventId": "updates.eventId",
      "data": "updates.data",
      "count": "1"
    }
  ).execute()
```

Comment: But this allows only one match condition. How would it be with multiple? Or how would I add an additional conditon to each "whenMatchedUpdate"? It should be possible according to the Documentation but there is no code example in the Docu

Comment: If you want to add multiple conditions, you can do it like this:

    condition = "events.eventId = updates.eventId AND events.date = updates.date"